# postgres: concat string with array

Tags: postgresql

Assume we have a column with text with next structure: `["A", "B", "C"]`,
how to concat it with array `ARRAY['A','C','D','E']` and produce string `["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]` (string without repeated elements)?

postgres version is 9.4.8

Column data can be `["A", "B", "C"]` or null, how it can be concatenated with `ARRAY['A','C','D','E']` (actually it can be a string, but i need to add elements to existing string without repeating them), resulting string must have the following pattern `["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]`

Solved with script, that alternate db via pdo.

Comment: Please explain the role of double quotes in your example.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter they already exist in db, and store settings, that parsed by app, i want to replace existing string with a new one that constructed from algorithm described in question.

Comment: Do you need double quotes in the new string, too? What do possible actual strings look like? Can they have a double quote *inside* the string? Are they *always* upper case? Put all the defining information into the question, and please always declare your version of Postgres.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter can you please explain, how it can be applied to update statement?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT array_agg(x) FROM
   (SELECT * FROM unnest(ARRAY['A', 'B', 'C'])
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM unnest(ARRAY['A','C','D','E'])
   ) a(x);
┌─────────────┐
│  array_agg  │
├─────────────┤
│ {D,B,E,C,A} │
└─────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Transform the string to another array, unnest both and take the ordered `UNION` of both to form a new array:

```
SELECT ARRAY(
   SELECT * FROM unnest(ARRAY['A','C','D','E'])
   UNION 
   SELECT * FROM unnest(string_to_array(translate('["A", "B", "C"]', '[]"', ''), ', '))
   ORDER BY 1
   );
```

I removed the characters `[]"` to proceed with the simple case. You would need to explain why you have them / need them ...

An [ARRAY constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) is faster for the simple case.